# Prevent repeating query within SerializerMethodField s

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

So i got my serializer called like this:

```
result_serializer = TaskInfoSerializer(tasks, many=True)
```

And the serializer:

```
class TaskInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    done_jobs_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    total_jobs_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    task_status = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('task_id', 'task_name', 'done_jobs_count', 'total_jobs_count', 'task_status')

    def get_done_jobs_count(self, obj):
        qs  = Job.objects.filter(task__task_id=obj.task_id, done_flag=1)
        condition = False
        # Some complicate logic to determine condition that I can't reveal due to business
        result = qs.count() if condition else 0
        # this function take around 3 seconds
        return result

    def get_total_jobs_count(self, obj):
        qs = Job.objects.filter(task__task_id=obj.task_id)
        # this query take around 3-5 seconds
        return qs.count()

    def get_task_status(self, obj):
        done_count    = self.get_done_jobs_count(obj)
        total_count    = self.get_total_jobs_count(obj)
        if done_count >= total_count:
            return 'done'
        else:
            return 'not yet'
```

When the get_task_status function is called, it call other 2 function and make those 2 costly query again.
Is there any best way to prevent that? And I dont really know the order of those functions to be called, is it based on the order declare in Meta's fields? Or above that?

**Edit:**
The logic in get_done_jobs_count is a bit complicate and I cannot make it into a single query when get task

**Edit 2:**
I just bring all those count function into model and use cached_property
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.functional
But it raise another question: Is that number reliable? I don't understand much about django cache, is that cached_property is only exist for this instance (just until the API get list of tasks return a response) or will it exist for sometime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just try cached_property and it did resolve the problem.

Model:

```
from django.utils.functional import cached_property
from django.db import models

class Task(models.Model):
    task_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    task_name = models.CharField(default='')

    @cached_property
    def done_jobs_count(self):
        qs  = self.jobs.filter(done_flag=1)
        condition = False
        # Some complicate logic to determine condition that I can't reveal due to business
        result = qs.count() if condition else 0
        # this function take around 3 seconds
        return result

    @cached_property
    def total_jobs_count(self):
        qs = Job.objects.filter(task__task_id=obj.task_id)
        # this query take around 3-5 seconds
        return qs.count()

    @property
    def task_status(self):
        done_count    = self.done_jobs_count
        total_count    = self.total_jobs_count
        if done_count >= total_count:
            return 'done'
        else:
            return 'not yet'
```

Serializer:

```
class TaskInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('task_id', 'task_name', 'done_jobs_count', 'total_jobs_count', 'task_status')
```

Comment: Fanatastic solution.

My query time is at least 5 times faster using this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could annotate those values to avoid making extra queries. So the queryset passed to the serializer would look something like this (it might change depending on the Django version you're using and the related query name for jobs):

```
tasks = tasks.annotate(
    done_jobs=Count('jobs', filter=Q(done_flag=1)),
    total_jobs=Count('jobs'),
)
result_serializer = TaskInfoSerializer(tasks, many=True)
```

Then the serializer method would look like:

```
def get_task_status(self, obj):
    if obj.done_jobs >= obj.total_jobs:
        return 'done'
    else:
        return 'not yet'
```

**Edit**: a cached_property won't help you if you have to call the method for each task instance (which seems the case). The problem is not so much the calculation but whether you have to hit the database for each separate task. You have to focus on getting all the information needed for the calculation in a single query. If that's impossible or too complicated, maybe think about changing the data structure (models) in order to facilitate that.

Comment: This is a good approach. But my problem is a bit more complicate than I have stated, sorry for that (I need to delete some important logic due to company privacy and forget it would make a difference). I've edited the question. The problem is I can't get rid of those function at all due to some business logic must be run to determine the final result of the count function, which I can't merge into the tasks query_set. So I must do it anyway, I just look for the way to not do it again in get_task_status function. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I just try cached_property (I've edited the question) and it did resolve the problem. But it raise another question: Is that number reliable? I don't understand much about django cache, is that cached_property is only exist for this instance (just until the API get list of tasks return a response) or will it exist for sometime?

Comment: I don't think cached_property is gonna improve the performance at all. I assume you've added the method to the Task model, in which case it wouldn't make any difference since each time you'd be calling the method on a separate task instance. The result would be realiable, but you'd be still making the calculation for every task.

Comment: It did improved. Since the normally, the get_done_jobs_count take 3s, get_total_jobs_count take 3s, get_task_status call them both again take 6s, in total it take 12s. With cache property now it only take 6s (the get_task_status take no time anymore)

Comment: You're right, I didn't realize you have serializer fields for those methods. In that case it will obviously help, since the second time you call the methods the result has already been cached. But you still have a huge problem if those methods take 3 seconds and you have to call them for each task, it'll be too slow anyway.

Comment: Yes it is. But it contain too many business logic making me cannot get rid of them. But then again, the most consume time one is the count. That I will find out again another time in another question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Using **iterator()**  and counting Iterator might solve your problem.

```
job_iter = Job.objects.filter(task__task_id=obj.task_id).iterator()
count = len(list(job_iter))
return count
```

You can use select_related() and prefetch_related() for Retrieve everything at once if you will need them.

***Note***: if you use **iterator()** to run the query, **prefetch_related()** calls will be ignored

You might want to go through documentation for [optimisation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/optimization/)

Comment: This is a bad idea. It doesn't solve the problem of making an extra query per task, and using `len(queryset)` instead of `queryset.count()` will probably cause more performance issues.

Comment: @MoisésHiraldo I would like to know what kind of performance issue it will cause. thanks in advance

Comment: Using the `len` function will load the whole queryset in memory, which can become expensive if it contains a lot of objects. There's no need for it as we only want the number of objects and the database can do that job. Using count you have the same number of queries and less memory consumption.